# Using setInvernal to call a query function every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really easy one here, I'm sure - I'm a beginner who's struggling to integrate setInterval into my jQuery. I currently have this function, which rotates two images upon clicking them. I want this to happen automatically (every few seconds), and can't seem to find the right way to use setInterval.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot for any help.

Philip

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").click(function () {
          $(this).animate({ "width": "0px", "margin-left": "135px" }, 500, function () {
              $(this).parent().hide();
              $(this).width(0);
              $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").animate({ "width": "271px", "margin-left": "0px" });
              $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil2").show();
          });
      });
      $("#spinitemholder2 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").click(function () {
          $(this).animate({ "width": "0px", "margin-left": "135px" }, 500, function () {
              $(this).parent().hide();
              $(this).width(0);
              $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").animate({ "width": "271px", "margin-left": "0px" });
              $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1").show();
          });
      });

});
```

Comment: Does it work without `setInterval`? Because you have a syntax error here: `"#spinitemholder<xsl:value-of select="position()" /> .sponsorFlipphil1 img"`

Comment: I think you left a piece of XSLT in your code. If it doesn't matter to the issue at hand, could you please remove it?

Comment: What is the problem? Why do you think it's `setInterval`'s fault?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've removed the xslt, sorry about that. It was just used to create generate IDs for the images. Also, the problem is the code stops working when I try to use setInterval. I was wondering what the correct way would be to add it to my code. The code works when I use it as it is.

Comment: Aren't all of your `this` references invalid when using the `setInterval` method? I mean, `this` in a click references to the element clicked, while `this` in a method call (which `setInterval` essentially is) references to the method it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").trigger("click");
  $("#spinitemholder2 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").trigger("click");
}, 5000);
```

You have to use "trigger". I would suggest to reset interval when user clicks one of the images. An easy way would be:

```
var interval = 0;
function startNewInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval); // clear previous one
  interval = setInterval(function () { // start new interval
    $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").trigger("click");
    $("#spinitemholder2 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").trigger("click");
  }, 5000);
}

$("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").click(function () {
  $(this).animate({ "width": "0px", "margin-left": "135px" }, 500, function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).width(0);
    $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").animate({ "width": "271px", "margin-left": "0px" });
    $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil2").show();
    startNewInterval();
  });
});

$("#spinitemholder2 .sponsorFlipphil2 img").click(function () {
  $(this).animate({ "width": "0px", "margin-left": "135px" }, 500, function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).width(0);
    $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img").animate({ "width": "271px", "margin-left": "0px" });
    $("#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1").show();
    startNewInterval();
  });
});

startNewInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
setInterval( function(){
    $('#spinitemholder1 .sponsorFlipphil1 img, #spinitemholder2 .sponsorFlipphil2 img' ).click();
}, 2000);
```

and see if it works. (*just to test the code, **this is not the suggested way to do it***)

Comment: @user, run this after you execute the code in your question. If it does not work then your original code should not work either..